# How do you display user photo in templates?

Tags: users

I tried using the following but it's not working:

```
{% if entry.author.photoUrl|length %}
<img src="{{ entry.author.photoUrl(84) }}" alt="" />
{% else %}
no photo
{% endif %}
```

Also, another question of mine is... when i upload a user photo on the profile tab, am I suppose to see the photo's thumbnail? All I see is the upload box with the button but the file seemed to have uploaded successfully to /craft/storage/userphotos

Comment: Forgot to mention that I get "no photo" as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the image that I was trying to upload had issues. So, my code was working. Image upload had issues and there were no errors to tell you that. But we're good now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should see the photo thumbnail in the list of users after you upload the photo. Your exact code works for me, so I think something has gone wrong with the photo upload.

Comment: Well, both original and 100 folders contain the uploaded image... so how is there something wrong with the photo upload? How can I diagnose the problem here?